# Every inner product space is a metric space.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, inner-products

Show that every inner product space is a metric space.

To show this should I set the distance metric as $d(x,y) = \langle x-y,x-y\rangle$, then show properties of being metric space such as $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$ etc.?
If so the point I do not understand is why we set metric as $d(x,y) = \langle x-y,\ x-y \rangle$ (this metric is mentioned in [wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InnerProduct.html))

Comment: you should use $d(x,y) = \sqrt{\langle x-y, x-y\rangle}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is wrong. It should be $d(x,y)=\sqrt{\langle x-y,x-y\rangle}$ because the map $x\mapsto\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$ is a norm. And, whenever you have a norm $\lVert\cdot\rVert$, the map $(x,y)\mapsto\lVert x-y\rVert$ is a distance.

Answer (score 1):

The inner product *induces* a norm via
$$||x||:=\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$$
and then, the norm *induces* a metric via
$$d(x,y):=||x-y||$$
which is precisely what is mentioned in the comment above. In general, one has the relation $\text{Inner Product Spaces}\subset\text{Normed Vector Spaces}\subset\text{Metric Spaces}$.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting $d(x,y)=||x-y||$. So your metric here comes from the norm. You can check that it satisfies the required metric conditions.

We are not sating that this is the only way to choose a metric on the space, but it is one way.